# Is it possible to define more than one post-validator in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony-1.4

I need to perform several post-validations in a Symfony form. First time I came across this issue I wrote this:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorCallback(array(
    'callback' => array($this, 'checkStatusHasMethod'))
));
```

since I only wanted to check a certain situation.

But as the application has grown, I need now to perform additional checks. I would like to keep every validation isolated in different methods, instead of having a big `checkX` method where everything is kept together.

Is it possible to associate a `sfPostValidator` with more than one method or create several `sfPostValidator` instances in `validatorSchema`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mergePostValidator() (or similar, can't remember the exact method name)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there's a validator called sfValidatorAnd() that allows you to do that.

Edit : you can do that :

```
new sfValidatorAnd(
    array(
        new sfValidatorString(),
        new sfValidatorRegex(),
    )
);
```